# Error about Dedekind cuts in this construction of $b^x$ (from the book "Calculus Unlimited")

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I was wondering if someone could help me find a correct proof of a fact I found in the textbook *Calculus Unlimited* (1981), by Jerrold Marsden and Alan J Weinstein ([link to online copy](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/25054/))

In particular, on page 134-135, they attempt a proof of constructing $b^x$.

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Now, the part that I believe is wrong is after the word 'Similarly' on page 135. It appears to me that they're trying to use a convexity argument to get both a lower and upper bound but this actually doesn't work. The inequality they write down in the second case I believe is just incorrect and the argument falls apart after this. Solved Exercise 11, a proof of the usual convexity bound, actually is just a rearrangement of the correct first inequality on page 135 but this cannot be useful in obtaining the other bound.

> [image]

In short, can anyone find a corrected proof of the stated fact in this textbook? Thanks in advance for your help.

PS. The tag for this should be dedekind_cuts but this is not a created tag yet.

Comment: Shouldn't a tag for 'dedekind-cuts' have appeared magically just when it was needed? :)

Comment: 'real-numbers' seems like a good proxy. Feel free to edit if you disagree :-)